# manipulate the DOM in electron with a menu item

Tags: node.js, electron

I wish to create a dialog box (a modal window) that will display when a user clicks the "About" link on my application menu. I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
let menuTemplate = {
  menu: [
    {
      label: 'About',
      click () {
        let about = document.querySelector('.hidden');
        about.classList.remove('hidden');
      }
    }
  ]
}

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

The message that I get is that 'document is not defined'  I believe this is because the menu for the electron app is in the main process and the DOM for the page is in a renderer process.

I know there is a way for communication between the main process and remote process but it is really confusing to me.  Can someone give me an idea of what the next steps are?

ps I'm using NodeJS and Express with Electron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now there are two ways you can consider going about this: one can be done in the main process, the other requires cross-process messaging.

---

## Main Process (alone)

Using the main process, we can import the `dialog` class during our require statement, and then use the method (as suggested by Arun in another answer):

`dialog.showMessageBox([browserWindow, ]options[, callback])`

This will display a dialog box native to the operating system.  You may even find you want to use this for some things people do in your renderer process, but I'll get on to that next.

## Inter-process Communication

Your tray menu will have been instantiated in your main process, but the result of the event has to take place in the renderer process to show your modal.

In the main process, we can import `ipcMain`, and in the renderer process - you guessed it, `ipcRenderer`.

In your click event, you can do use the `BrowserWindow#webContents#send` method to send your render an event, let's call it 'ShowMyModal':

`myWindowInstance.webContents.send('ShowMyModal');`

Now, in the main process, we can listen for this event with the `ipcMain` object.

```
ipcMain.on('ShowMyModal', function () {
  // the modal event has fired!

  $('#myModal').show();
});
```

---

You will probably find inter-process communication for this sort of stuff. Get used to throwing IPC events back and forth, it really shows the beauty of electron and its renderer process.

Comment: I used a modified version of your answer by using webcontents.send() in the menu file and the IPC call in a JavaScript file that is used on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create dialogs/popup windows using electron dialog.

```
dialog.showMessageBox([browserWindow, ]options[, callback])
```

Please check this docs for more info: 
https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/

Comment: Thank you reminding me about electron dialogs.  I will keep this in mind for future projects.